# Selenium webdriver, python TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using the Selenium extended module and am getting this error on one of the functions I set up with it, despite other functions working fine.

function that works:

```py
class SeleniumExtended:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver=driver
        self.default_timeout=10

    def wait_and_input_text(self, locator, text, timeout=None):
        timeout= timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout

        WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator)
        ).send_keys(text)`
```

function with Type error:

```
def wait_until_visibility_of_element(self, locator, timeout=None):

    timeout= timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout

    WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator))
```

Error:

```
timeout = ('css selector', 'body > header > div > div > div.main-nav__logo > a > img')

    def wait_until_visibility_of_element(self, locator, timeout=None):

        timeout= timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout

>       WebDriverWait(self.driver, float(timeout)).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator))
E       TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'tuple'

..\src\SeleniumExtended.py:26: TypeError


FAILED test_shawbrook_expriments.py::Test_shawex::test_shawmr - TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'tuple'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
timeout = ('css selector', 'body > header > div > div > div.main-nav__logo > a > img')
```

shows that you've assigned a locator to the `timeout` variable somewhere in your code. I don't see it in the code you posted so it's somewhere else. Find and fix that and your problem should be solved.

---

NOTE: You've got these lines of code in several places

```
def wait_until_visibility_of_element(self, locator, timeout=None):
    timeout = timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout
```

Where you have a default value of `None` for `timeout`. You check if `timeout` is `None` and if it is, set it to `self.default_timeout`. Why not just use

```
def wait_until_visibility_of_element(self, locator, timeout=self.default_timeout):
```

instead and then you can skip the `None` check?